# Como agendar uma tarefa recorrente no linux?

Tags: linux, agendamento

Que comando posso usar para agendar uma tarefa recorrente no linux? Gostaria também de enviar o retorno do comando por email automaticamente. Qual é a ferramenta mais adequada?

Comment: Para isso você usa um recurso do linux chamado Cron. Você pode saber mais sobre cron nesse link: http://www.infowester.com/linuxcron.php E para o envio do email eu nunca precisei fazer, então não tenho muita experiência, mas talvez esse link possa lhe ajudar: http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/sending-email-alerts-through-cron/ Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Existe uma ferramenta para linux chamada crontab. Ela é nativa. Para você editar o arquivo basta dar o comando `crontab -e`.

O crontab tem o seguinte formato:

[minutos] [horas] [dias do mês] [mês] [dias da semana] [usuário] [comando]

O preenchimento de cada campo é feito da seguinte maneira:

- **Minutos:** informe números de 0 a 59;
- **Horas:** informe números de 0 a 23;
- **Dias do mês:** informe números de 0 a 31;
- **Mês:** informe números de 1 a 12;
- **Dias da semana:** informe números de 0 a 7;
- **Usuário:** é o usuário que vai executar o comando (não é necessário especificá-lo se o arquivo do próprio usuário for usado);
- **Comando:** a tarefa que deve ser executada.

---

- **crontab -e:** serve para editar o arquivo atual do crontab e criar um, caso não exista;
- **crontab -l:** mostra o conteúdo atual do crontab;
- **crontab -r:** remove o arquivo atual do crontab.

---

Para enviar email, basta você utilizar este comando

```
59 */6 * * * script.sh | mail -s “Subject of Mail” someother@address.com
```

---

Você pode ler mais sobre nesse link.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 7):

Use o [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) para o agendamento. É a ferramenta padrão.

Redirecione o output com um pipe (|) para o comando [mail](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mail) para enviar o output por email.

Exemplo de entrada em `/etc/crontab`:

```
00 09-18 * * * /home/exemplo/bin/check-db-status | mail -s "db status" sa@example.com
```

Vai rodar de uma em uma hora de 9 às 18, mandando o output para sa@example.com.

Answer (score 3):

Para agendar uma tarefa no Linux, você deve utilizar o CRON. O cron pode ser interpretado como um serviço do Linux que é carregado durante o processo de boot do sistema. Trata-se de uma ferramenta que permite programar a execução de comandos e processos de maneira repetitiva ou apenas uma única vez.

Para executar as tarefas, o cron usa uma espécie de tabela conhecida como crontab. O arquivo crontab geralmente fica localizado no diretório /etc, mas também pode estar em um diretório que cria um crontab para cada usuário do sistema (geralmente em /var/spool/cron/), tudo depende da distribuição linux.

**Mão na massa**

O primeiro passo é abrir o crontab. Para isso, você pode usar editores de textos como vi, emacs ou nano (eu prefiro o pico, mas verifique a sua distribuição). Também é possível digitar o comando crontab -e para editar o arquivo exclusivo de seu usuário.

O crontab tem o seguinte formato:

*[minutos] [horas] [dias do mês] [mês] [dias da semana] [usuário] [comando]*

O preenchimento de cada campo é feito da seguinte maneira:

- *Minutos*: informe números de 0 a 59;
- *Horas*: informe números de 0 a 23;
- *Dias do mês*: informe números de 0 a 31;
- *Mês*: informe números de 1 a 12;
- *Dias da semana*: informe números de 0 a 7;
- *Usuário*: é o usuário que vai executar o comando (não é necessário especificá-lo se o arquivo do próprio usuário for usado);
- *Comando*: a tarefa que deve ser executada.

Obs.:

```
 - Você pode informar * (asterisco) para especificar uma execução constante. Por exemplo, se o campo dias do mês conter *, o comando relacionado será executado todos os dias;
 - Você também pode informar intervalos no preenchimento, separando os números de início e fim através de - (hífen). Por exemplo, se no campo horas for informando 2-5, o comando relacionado será executado às 2, 3, 4 e 5 horas. E se o comando tiver que ser executado às 2 horas, entre 15 e 18 horas e às 22 horas? Basta informar 2,15-18,22. Nestes casos, você separa os parâmetros por vírgula.
```

Por exemplo:

```
#tarefa infowester 
30 0,21-23 3,14 \* \* echo "Não entre em pânico" > /home/alecrim/infowester.txt
```

Neste exemplo, a frase "Não entre em pânico" é inserida no arquivo infowester.txt, dentro do diretório /home/alecrim/, aos 30 minutos das 21, 22, 23 e 0 horas, nos dias 3 e 14, em todos os meses e em todos os dias da semana. Repare na linha "#tarefa infowester". Trata-se de um comentário. Digite # e tudo o que for digitado na linha não será considerado pelo cron. É um recurso útil para inserir descrições quando se tem várias tarefas a serem executadas.

**Comandos do crontab**

*crontab -e*: conforme já informado, serve para editar o arquivo atual do crontab e criar um, caso não exista;

*crontab -l*: este comando mostra o conteúdo atual do crontab;

*crontab -r*: remove o arquivo atual do crontab.

[image: Comandos CRONTAB]

Fonte: Infowester (http://www.infowester.com/linuxcron.php)

**OUTRA SOLUÇÃO**

Talvez uma forma mais fácil que você também utilizar o arquivo *init.d*. Este arquivo é encontrado na maioria massante das Distribuições Linux, no caminho */etc/init.d*, onde todos os comando encontrados nesse arquivo são executados toda vez que você inicializa o sistema. Para utilizar essa função, basta abrir esse arquivo com um editor de texto e colocar os comandos desejado.

**ATENÇÃO: Todos os comandos só são executados apenas na inicialização do sistema.**

Answer (score 2):

Lembrando que quando você utiliza o `crontab -e` não precisa colocar usuário na execução da atividade. Com o `crontab -e` já é nativo executar pelo root. Já no `/etc/crontab` é preciso pôr o usuário.