# Como executar código PHP apenas uma vez por dia?

Tags: php

Estou usando as API's do facebook e do instagram em um projeto. Eu basicamente faço a consulta de posts respectivamente de cada rede social e insiro no banco de dados do wordpress, salvei o ID de cada post e faço uma verificação antes de inserir para não inserir posts duplicados.

Porém sempre que carrego o site, ele demora pra carregar pois ele faz a busca por posts no facebook e no instagram, isso tá prejudicando o desempenho do site.

O que eu quero fazer é que essa busca por novos posts no instagram e facebook seja feita apenas uma vez por dia. Se um usuário entrar no site e executar a busca, os próximos usuários não vão executar mais essa busca. E dai no próximo dia o primeiro usuário executa a busca e os demais não e assim por diante.

Comment: **Relacionado** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2818/3635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por mais que já tenha uma resposta aceita, há uma forma bem mais simples do que criar uma conexão com o banco de dados, mencionado pelo @Haroldo_OK.
Para executar o código somente uma vez por dia, pode se salvar um arquivo, que contém o timestamp do dia seguinte. Sempre que o PHP for executado, os timestamps são comparados. Se tiver passado mais de 1 dia, o código é executado novamente.

```
if (file_get_contents('ultima_verificacao') < time()) {
    file_put_contents('ultima_verificacao', strtotime('+1 day', time()));
    echo "Execute código diário aqui";
}
```

Comment: Ou, se você precisar de ganhos extremos de performance, pode-se usar o memcached, ou solução similar.

Answer (score 3):

Simplesmente guarde em uma tabela de banco de dados a data da última execução da busca. Quando um usuário executar a busca, você compara essa data com a atual; se forem diferentes, você executa o código que tem que executar uma vez por dia e atualiza a data da última execução; se a data for a mesma, não vai ser necessário executar novamente.

Comment: Vai utilizar um banco de dados só pra isso? A performance sofre com isso. Salvar um arquivo seria bem mais simples e mais rápido, em questões de legibilidade e performance.

Comment: De fato foi apenas um exemplo; na verdade, precisa-se de algum meio de armazenar dados, seja banco seja um arquivo, seja o memcached, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Outra maneira de obter o mesmo resultado é utilizar um agendador de tarefas (no Linux chama-se CRON) para que a execução da carga seja realizada automaticamente pelo Sistema Operacional, preferencialmente fora de horário de pico, sem comprometer/concorrer com os acessos ao seu app.

Uma referência da wikipedia:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

Comment: Há vantagens e desvantagens de usar o CRON; a vantagem é que pode-se agendar a execução da rotina para um horário onde ninguém esteja usando o sistema; a desvantagem é que a rotina vai ser executada mesmo que ninguém vá usar a rotina naquele determinado dia. No final das contas, vai depender da necessidade.