# Resetar Tabela mysql automaticamente

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tenho um banco de dados que armazena alguns leads, é possível fazer com que as tabelas deste banco sejam resetadas todo dia a certa hora ou até ela chegar a tantas linhas?

Uso o phpmyadmin no cpanel.

Comment: Sim é possível, pode criar um script (que executa o truncate) e agendar ele no cron mais detalhes em: [Como agendar uma tarefa recorrente no linux?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2818/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer com um evento:

```
CREATE EVENT evento_diario
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY
        STARTS '2016-11-01 00:00:00' -- Data e hora para iniciar
    COMMENT 'Limpar tabela XPTO'
    DO
        TRUNCATE XPTO;
```

Se quiser fazer baseado em X linhas, basta criar uma trigger..