# Como agendar tarefas com base no tempo (Cron) usando PHP ?

Tags: php, javascript, cron, e-commerce

Estou a desenvolover um modulo no prestashop, e preciso agendar algumas tarefas com base no tempo. Por exemplo : No dia **X** execute a funcao **Y** do meu modulo.

Existe uma forma de interagir com o modulo cronjob do prestashhop ?
Ha uma outra solucao pra isso ?
Estou densevolvendo em PHP, uma solucao em javascript também seria válida.

Comment: [Como agendar uma tarefa recorrente no linux?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2818/91)

Comment: @rray nao estou a usar Linux.

Comment: O módulo de cron do PrestaShop só funciona com linux nativamente. Em windows ele só funciona ao ser acessado depois do agendamento (o sistema verifica se passou da data no acesso, e executa as tarefas em caso positivo).

Answer (score 1):

Então, o PHP é uma linguagem que apenas coleta e processa os dados provendo um resultado, portanto não tem funções nativas de cron e nem deve-se tentar burla-la para que tenha. (Ou seja, processa o dado que tem que processar e morre logo em seguida)

Bom, agora seu sistema operacional é diferente, ele pode criar verificar um arquivo regularmente(crontab) e executar determinada instrução como seja especificado.

Exemplificando:

```
# [Quando vai rodar] [Comando que vai rodar]
  * 1 * * * php      /var/www/site/public/index.php --module=z --action=y
```

Ou seja, especifiquei que o comando "/var/www/site/public/index.php --module=z --action=y" vai rodar todo dia as 1 hr.

Enfim, **a configuração pode mudar conforme o sistema operacional, portanto recomendo que aprenda o conceito** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) de uma cron, e aplique conforme o seu sistema.