# Agendar a execução de uma página PHP

Tags: php, agendamento

Estou fazendo um webservice em PHP, esse webservice precisará ser executado todos os dias em um determinado horário, como posso fazer o agendamento pra ser executado essa rotina de forma automática?

Comment: [Como agendar uma tarefa recorrente no linux?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2818/91)

Comment: Você pode usar o [crontab](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHZL_pt-BRBR689BR689&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cron) do linux para rodar um script php