# Excluir automaticamente um registro de uma tabela após um intervalo de tempo

Tags: mysql, sql

Como faço para que após um intervalo de tempo o registro seja apagado automaticamente, como em um carrinho de compras, por exemplo?

Comment: Você terá que fazer agendamento de tarefas no seu servidor onde esta instalado o MySQL. Mas isso não é função do MySQL e sim do Sistema Operacional.

Comment: Pode usar o cronjobs do linux. [Como agendar uma tarefa recorrente no linux?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2818/91)

Comment: Você pode fazer com o MySQL sim, pode agendar um evento e rodar uma instrução, segue link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: @arllondias é isso mesmo que eu preciso. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu utilizo Scheduled Tasks com o comando CREATE EVENT do próprio MySQL. Referência não oficial do [Event Scheduler aqui](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/).

Exemplo da referência acima:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT `archive_blogs` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2011-07-24 03:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

    -- copy deleted posts
    INSERT INTO blog_archive (id, title, content) 
    SELECT id, title, content
    FROM blog
    WHERE deleted = 1;

    -- copy associated audit records
    INSERT INTO audit_archive (id, blog_id, changetype, changetime) 
    SELECT audit.id, audit.blog_id, audit.changetype, audit.changetime 
    FROM audit
    JOIN blog ON audit.blog_id = blog.id
    WHERE blog.deleted = 1;

    -- remove deleted blogs and audit entries
    DELETE FROM blog WHERE deleted = 1;

END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Obs: o recurso precisa ser habilitado através do comando `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Documentação oficial do MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: Já haviam citado o Event Schedule e foi de grande ajuda, seu exemplo ajudou ainda mais. Muito brigado.